# Selecionar HASH Code SHA256 NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sha-256

Como eu faço pra selecionar o código pra HASH no NodeJS?

Eu tenho um sistema feito em outra linguagem com senhas encryptadas com SHA256

A função de encryptação lá é assim:

```
#define HASH_CODE = 'WEASDSAEWEWAEAWEAWEWA';
SHA256_PassHash(HASH_CODE, password, 64);
```

A hash aqui ficou (pra senha 123): 8A8E0E514F3A1F3D160C58C99BC66C81A10256E6A3462002A53ADACAD6C43EAB

Primeiro parametro é o código da HASH, o segundo é o valor a ser encryptado e o terceiro é a base64

Consegui fazer encryptação no NodeJS, mas não tenho controle do código da HASH, então os sistemas não criam a mesma HASH, como eu faço pra selecionar o código da HASH ao registrar no NodeJS para que ele possa se comunicar com esse outro sistema?

```
const code = 'WEASDSAEWEWAEAWEAWEWA';
const normal = 'anne';
const crypto = require('crypto');
const encryptado = crypto
    .createHash('sha256')
    .update(normal)
    .digest('base64');
console.log(encryptado);
```

A hash aqui ficou (pra senha 123): 8A8E0E514F3A1F3D160C58C99BC66C81A10256E6A3462002A53ADACAD6C43EAB

Um exemplo de código compativel:
login.php

```
<?php require_once('../mysql_conn.php'); ?> 
    <?php
    session_start();
    $HASH_SENHA = 'WEASDSAEWEWAEAWEAWEWA';

    if(isset($_SESSION['Username']))
    {
        header("location: ../myaccount.php");
        exit();
    } 
    if(isset($_POST['usr']) && isset($_POST['psw']) && isset($_POST['botao'])) 
    { 
        $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($MYSQL_CONNECT, $_POST['usr']);  
        $senha = strtoupper(hash("sha256", $_POST['psw'] . $HASH_SENHA));  
        $query = mysqli_query($MYSQL_CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE Username='$usuario' AND Senha='$senha' LIMIT 1");  

        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) < 1)  
        {
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert('Incorrect Username or Password.');
                        window.location = '../login.php';
                  </script>";
            exit();
        }
        else 
        {
            //login efetuado 
            $dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);  


            if (isset($_SESSION['loc'])) {
                header("location:".$_SESSION['loc']);
            }
            else header("location:../index.php");

        }  
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Segundo sua pergunta não há problema (ignorando os problemas de segurança óbvio), mas em ambos o resultado da hash é igual, segundo você. Os dois casos geram `8A8E0E514F3A1F3D160C58C99BC66C81A10256E6A3462002A53ADACAD6C43EAB`.

Comment: Se sua pergunta estiver errada, e o NodeJS gera um código diferente, você tem que concanetar o `code`, como `.update(normal + code)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você possivelmente nunca conseguirá gerar a mesma hash, pois se trata de uma forma diferente de criptografia. A questão é comparar as hashs para saber se ambas trata da mesma informação encriptada. Esse tipo de criptografia é diferente, por exemplo, de MD5 que gera a mesma hash toda vez.

Outra dica, é invés de usar a bcrypt, utilize a bcryptjs, por ser mais rápida e evitar alguns problemas. (tive problemas em usa-las em funções lambda da aws). Vi que você usa uma outra ainda, se tudo estiver ok com ela, sem problema. (mas provavelmente o código irá mudar um pouco)

user-update.js

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

// se receber a senha para atualização, atualize a mesma
if (user.password) user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, 10)
```

auth.js

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

if (userFromDB) {
    const { id } = userFromDB

    if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, userFromDB.password)) {
      const token = jwt.sign({ id }, 'your-secret')

      return response200({ token })
    }
  }
```

O código não está totalmente completo, pois como utilizo funções lambda, e talvez você não, coloquei apenas o trecho para você entender o funcionamento da bcryptjs.

Além disso, utilizo JWT para autenticação. Se ainda não sabe como fará isso, dê uma estudada nessa ferramenta pois é muito interessante, talvez te ajuda também.

Caso ainda tenha mais alguma dúvida, não hesite em perguntar.